# How to just create a mock file with specific content in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, python-unittest

This is my current code:

```
with open('testfile', 'w') as test_file:
        test_file.write("Test Content.")
some_variable = ('testfile') ## this some_variable is used for testing(parsing content etc)
os.remove("testfile")
```

Need help to figure if I can achieve this without creating and deleting actual file.
I tried a few ways, but they did not work. Any help is appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: This is a strange question. What do you mean by "Mock" file? If you create a file pointer with "open('testfile', 'w')" this will always either create a new file or overwrite an existing file.

If you don't want the code to execute for debug purposes, you could wrap the section in an 'if False:' statement.

just an fyi: 'some_variable' is actually creating a tuple (something similar to a list/array) with one string in it, not sure what you're trying to accomplish! Write me back and I will try my best to help!

Comment: Basically some_variable is consumed by other methods to play with string ""Test Content."

Comment: But your code here writes "Test Content." to a file, then populates `some_variable` with the string "testfile". Do you actually want to reopen the file and reread the contents into `some_variable`?

Comment: Let's just forget about some_variable. Let's just say I want to create a file with some string content. But I do not want to actually create a file on the filesystem/memory which is visible to everyone. I want to instead create a "mock_file" with say string "test" on which if I use below, it would print 
f = open("mock_file", "r")
print(f.read())
>> test

Comment: Okay, I've updated my answer to include code you can use to set up a mock file with specific contents.

Comment: If you want to generally mock file system functions, you could also use [pyfakefs](https://github.com/jmcgeheeiv/pyfakefs) (Disclaimer: I'm a contributor to pyfakefs).

Answer (score 1):

If you like the dependency injection style, you can do it like this:

```
class ObjectUnderTest:
    def __init__(self, open_func=open, remove_func=os.remove):
        self.__open = open_func
        self.__remove = remove_func

    def methodUnderTest():
        # If you're writing to write...
        with self.__open('testfile', 'w') as test_file:
            test_file.write("Test Content.")

        # Or if you actually want to read...
        with self.__open('testfile', 'r') as test_file:
            some_variable = test_file.read()
        self.__remove("testfile")

class Tester:
    def test(self):
        # Use these four lines to set up a writeable file you can inspect later
        buffer = BytesIO()
        buffer.close = lambda: None
        mock_file = TextIOWrapper(buffer)
        mocked_open = lambda f, m: mock_file

        # Or *instead*, to set up a readable file with particular contents:
        from unittest.mock import mock_open
        mocked_open = mock_open(read_data="Test data.")
        
        # Then to patch os.remove:
        mocked_remove = lambda f: None
        
        testable = ObjectUnderTest(mocked_open, mocked_remove)
        testable.methodUnderTest()
```

If you want to inspect written data, patching `close` like that is particularly important to prevent the `with` from permanently closing the file stream, making the contents unreachable.

Comment: I think my question is not clear. I am not trying to test this function "def methodUnderTest()". What I am trying to do is to replace below 2 lines with mock object.                                           
```
with self.__open('testfile', 'w') as test_file:
            test_file.write("Test Content.")
```
Above 2 lines would create a file object on the filesystem which is accessible to everyone. I want to replace this with a mock file object, the scope of which is within this script. Please let me know if the ask is not clear. And thanks for helping out !

Comment: Yup, that's exactly what my code is doing. If it helps, I won't use the word "test" in my names anymore. I'll even move the mocking code to the body of your existing method if you want, although if it's like that, you won't be able to deploy the same code to work with real files...

Comment: The same way you would from a normal file, as shown under `# Or if you actually want to read...` above.

Comment: Please ignore that question :)

Comment: This is my actual library code
`file = <Inhouse file management class>.<in house read method>(<filepath/filename>)`
`print(file)`
In the unit test code, I want to use dummy file instead of real file in the <filepath/filename>
I am still unable to implement the above logic to this code

Comment: You can't do that by only changing the filename. You have to patch or inject a mock for `open`. The only alternative is to put the "open file" and "do stuff with the file" code into separate functions, so that you can test the "do stuff" part in isolation from any filesystem I/O.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that you are wanting a fake "File" for your program to work with, but you don't actually want the file to be written. You could make a dummy file class that acts like a file:

```
class MockFile:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename
        self.content = ""

    def write(self, string):
        self.content = string

    def append(self, string):
        self.content = self.content + string

    def read(self):
        return self.content
```

So in use with your example:

```
mock_file = MockFile('testfile')
some_variable = 'Test Content.'
mock_file.write(some_variable)
print(mock_file.read())
```

will produce

```
Test Content.
```

to append:

```
mock_file.append(" Hey, look some more text!")
print(mock_file.read())
```

will produce

```
Test Content. Hey, look some more text!
```

Comment: If they put the "open file" code and the "do stuff with the contents" code into separate functions (which would probably be a good idea anyway), something like this could work for the "do stuff" part. Otherwise, they will also need to patch `open`.